# Are there materials with more than two states that can be used in circuit design?

Tags: atomic-physics, material-science

Are there atoms or materials that have 3 or more states that can be used in circuit design? Can you provide any examples of such materials, and their possible applications to circuit design? And is there a maximum number of states that such a material can have?

I am interested in systems where each part has three possible states, so that e.g. a combination of two such systems have $3^2 = 9$ possible combined states:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about, please give context.

Comment: what is the maximum number of states can material have?

Comment: i want to design a circuit which using 3 states or maximum number of states

Comment: actually, it recebtly was announces a memristor with 6 states, and could reach up to ten, and this is classical computing using standard materials that could reach the market soon,  not quantum or exotic devices. see http://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/memory/sixstate-memristor-opens-door-to-weird-computing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any material and three of its energy levels.

Three-level systems also go by the name of [qutrit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qutrit). The linked article also links to some research results.

The number of states is completely irrelevant for theoretical purposes, it's just like calculating with decimal or binary calculations. As long as you can manipulate and entangle systems across many qubits, qutrits or whatever, you can define a universal gate set. It would maybe look differently, but unless any system is built, this is not really interesting.

There are however some physical differences (see the linked article), which might make them an interesting object to study.

**Edit:** Maybe, I'm misinterpreting the question, so let me add some references of quantum computation with qutrits:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0506031.pdf This proposes a design of a qutrit quantum computer with ion-traps.

http://www.mis.mpg.de/preprints/2014/preprint2014_9.pdf This is a preprint of a scientific reports article investigating the geometry of a qutrit quantum computer (proving essentially that the optimal circuit is the shortest path on the $SU(3^n)$)

Another interesting approach might be 
http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0272 
where they use qubits, qutrits, etc. to reduce the number of gates - but this seems not to be in the vein of your question, as it ultimately operates not only with qubits or qutrits, but rather with qubits and qutrits.

Comment: I saw some news stated that quantum computer has 3 states, is it true? what are the maximum number of states can material have?

Comment: I have interest in multi valued logic and extends its calculation in set theory, but i do not know how to draw when or and and concept not used any more in 3 valued logic, hope 3 valued circuit can help to know how it do in set theory or even calculation in algebra

Comment: What news did you see? There is, as of now, no quantum computer, hence it has no number of states. All theoretical models I know of, however, work with qubits (two-level systems) for simplicity. A description with qutrits should be equivalent as I stated above.

Comment: Martin, there is no quantum computer, because the devices needed are big, s.t. this domain is in infancy. But there is a whole literature about quantum computing, i.e. algorithms that seem simpler to implement with quantum particles than with classical means. About qutrits, I know for sure that Asher Peres, one of the fathers of the quantum computing, worked with them. I don't deal with this domain, but I know that Dr. Tal Mor, that did his PhD with Peres, is an expert in the domain, and can tell better.

Comment: @Sofia, I know why there is no quantum computer, although I'm working more on the mathematical side. I also know that there is some literature on qutrits - the Wikipedia article I linked to has a few links, but I also know that the overwhelming majority of the literature on quantum algorithms works with qubits instead of qutrits. As I understand it, if there is a speedup anywhere, it should be there with qubits, too, so in this sense, it doesn't matter.

Comment: But thanks for the name Tal Mor, maybe I'll have a look at what he does!

Comment: if divided energy level can represent many states, does it mean that more energy more states?

Comment: It's not really divided energy levels, but this: Take an atom, then it has many energy levels. You can mark the ground state by $|0\rangle$ and an excited state by $|1\rangle$ and another excited state by $|2\rangle$ and so forth. The drawback is that excited states are unstable, so decoherence destroys your state. This is why usually, you try to find stable to metastable states. See the famous Cirac/Zoller proposal for iron traps for an example: http://www.qudev.ethz.ch/phys4/studentspresentations/iontraps/CiracZoller1995.pdf

Comment: But yes, in order to 'activate' more energy levels, you'd need more energy.

Answer (score 1):

A typical particle that can have three states is the hydrogen atom in the ground state (or in general in an ℓ = 0 state), if J = ħ i.e. if the total spin (of the nucleus and of the electron) is ħ. This state has three possible projections of the spin on whatever direction, +ħ, 0, and -ħ.
Another typical particle with spin ħ is the deuterium nucleus, s.t. it has also three values of the spin projection on whatever direction.

Well, you can make your choice !

Good luck!

Comment: do more energy have more states? how to divide energy level into each states? which device can detect these states?